# Tracking intermediate values within Manipulate

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, nonlinear, system

I want to determine the intermediate values of

```
P[i][t] = {X[i][t], Y[i][t]}
```

for the following system of nonlinear differential equations:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

n = 3;

P[i_][t_] = {X[i][t], Y[i][t]};

p[j_, i_] = Norm[P[i][t] - P[j][t]];

A@p[j, i] = (a*(P[i][t] - P[j][t]))/Exp[b*p[j, i]];

R@p[j, i] = (c*(P[i][t] - P[j][t]))/p[j, i]^2;

summand1 = R@p[j, i] - A@p[j, i];

A@p[i, j] = (a*(P[j][t] - P[i][t]))/Exp[b*p[i, j]];

R@p[i, j] = (c*(P[j][t] - P[i][t]))/p[i, j]^2;

summand2 = A@p[i, j] - R@p[i, j];

sys = Table[D[P[i][t], t] == Sum[If[j < i, summand1, 0], {j, 1, n}] + Sum[If[i < j, summand2,
0], {j, 1, n}] + {.1 (1/Norm[{0, Y[i][t]} - P[i][t]] - 1/Norm[P[i][t] - {10, Y[i][t]}]), 
.1 (1/Norm[{X[i][t], -1} - P[i][t]] - 1/Norm[P[i][t] - {X[i][t], 3}])}, {i, 1, n}];

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{sys, P[1][0] == {1, 1}, P[2][0] == {2, 2}, P[3][0] == {3, 2}}, 
Table[P[i][t], {i, 1, n}], {t, 0, 100}, {a, b, c}];

Manipulate[ParametricPlot[sol[a, b, c] // Evaluate, {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, 
{0, 10}}, ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1], {{a, 1}, .1, 5}, {{b, 1}, .1, 5}, 
{{c, 1}, .1, 5}, {{T, 1}, .1, 100}]
```

My goal is to draw lines between each pair

```
P[i][t], P[j][t]
```

for $i \neq j$. Basically, my goal is drawing connections between the endpoints of the solution curves in order to visualize a certain equilibrium state (which might for example be an equilateral triangle in this case). For me it suffices to include the connections for

```
t = T
```

Is it possible to draw these lines within Manipulate?

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you are looking form, it could be a simple fix. For instance, you could add a `Polygon` object as an `Epilog` to your `ParametricPlot`, whose vertices are the values of the solution at $t=T$, i.e. something like:

```
Polygon[sol[a, b, c] /. t -> T]
```

Here is your minimally modified `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
    sol[a, b, c] // Evaluate, {t, 0, T},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}},
    ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1,
    (* This line below is the only change: *)
    Epilog -> {EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[None], Polygon[sol[a, b, c] /. t -> T]}
  ],
  {{a, 1}, .1, 5}, {{b, 1}, .1, 5}, {{c, 1}, .1, 5},
  {{T, 1}, .1, 100}
]
```

[image: with triangle]

Comment: Exactly what I was asking for (even better because you can see the triangle evolving in time!). Is there a build-in which can display the properties of polygons such as the lengths of the sides and the angles in between? By the way, as far as I understand `Polygon[sol[a, b, c] /. t -> T]` creates `n` lines (between 'endpoints') without giving us the choice to say create a triangle out of four solution curves? I am asking this because there's a phenomenon called clustering for greater values of `n` in which we don't want Mathematica to draw irrelevant lines between solution curves.

Comment: @E4M2227601 You are correct that `Polygon` will generate an $n$-dimensional polygon when given $n$ points. Can you specify how you would like to generate a triangle from four points? Are you looking for the convex hull of those points perhaps (see [`ConvexHullMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html)) ? Note also that your code fails if I change $n$ to e.g. 4, so I couldn't quite try it out.

Comment: That's because you also need 4 solution curves and thus 4 initial conditions (I tried `P[1][0] == {1, 0}, P[2][0] == {1, 1.5}, P[3][0] == {1.5, 2}, P[4][0] == {2, 2}` and got a nice polygon, for example the setup `a = 5` `b = .65` and `c = 4` gives a rhombus as the curves evolve in time). What I'm thinking of is for example $n = 6$ divided into 2 triangles (polygons). I want to specify the polygons between the curves by myself.